# S-57 layer not showing on ArcGis Runtime SDK for .NET (Windows Store)

Tags: arcgis

I have successfully used the ArcGis Runtime SDK to develop a mapping application for WPF in the past. I am now trying to make this work for a Windows Store application, but the S-57 ENC cells are simply not showing.

During debugging I can see that the initialization of the HydrographicS57Layer fails with the exception "Unspecified error. File not found : S57 dictionary not found."

This error happens inside the ArcGisRuntime dll.

I have created a ArcGis runtime deployment manifest including the Hydrographic (S57) symbology.

The problem occurs regardless whether I debug the application in Visual Studio or build a app package and deploy through Powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

For S-57, you have to tell ArcGIS Runtime where to find the symbol dictionary:

```
ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.SymbolsPath = @"arcgisruntime10.2.6\resources\symbols";
```